# I can't update package I forked anymore, was working a week ago

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, composer-php

I forked a php package and am using forked version in my local machine, I plan to extend the package, while I was working with it a week ago everything was working fine, today when I focused on this part of the application again and had to update the package with latest code I had pushed to repo, so I tried to update the package like

composer update author/package-name

and I also have this part in the composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/myproject/package-name"
    }
],
```

I suddenly get this:

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>
> - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.0.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version 
>     (7.1.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.0.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher (locked at v4.0.3) -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.0.3].

I currently have php 7.1.1 installed and am running laravel 5.4, I wonder why after a week or so where I was able to run the command above without a problem today I can't and what is also confusing me is this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

php requirement for laravel on the server is 5.6.4 or higher.

So why would symfony/event-dispatcher require 7.1.3 and why would laravel's own page claim version 5.4 min-requirment is php 5.6.4?

Anyone has any clues?

Comment: The composer.json of the [4.x branch of symfony/event-dispatcher](https://github.com/symfony/event-dispatcher/blob/4.0/composer.json) has’t been updated for 9 months. Looks like somewhere there’s been an update to requiring symfony/event-dispatcher 4.x rather than 3.x. Might be worth reporting a bug for that particular package.

Comment: funny thing is I was able to update this package just 7-8 days ago, what could have changed? Package could not have changed since I am getting my own version of it from the repo, I did some simple changes in code and did not touch anything inside that package composer.json, here it is if you would like to help me further: https://github.com/laracraft/laravel-theme/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: I don’t think I would be able to find the particular package, but I’ve posted an answer that should lead you to the root of the problem and help you solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3.4 and the 4.0 branch of the symfony/event-dispatcher package have different PHP requirements. It looks like a package inside your dependency tree has caused an update from symfony/event-dispatcher 3.4 to 4.0.

To find out why this package was installed, you can use Composer:

```
composer why symfony/event-dispatcher
```

You could also grep for `symfony/event-dispatcher` in the `composer.json` files in your vendor directory:

```
grep -r --include=composer.json symfony/event-dispatcher vendor/
```

You will most likely see that some of them work with both branches of that package, e.g.

```
…
"symfony/event-dispatcher": "~3.4|~4.0",
…
```

(Note that some of the entries, for example those with a `<3.4` value, are not from the `require`, but from the `conflict` section.)

You can try forcing your project to use a 3.x version of the symfony/event-dispatcher package. Add the following to your root composer.json:

```
"symfony/event-dispatcher": "<4.0"
```

This should force the installation of the 3.4 branch. But you might run into a dependency conflict if there’s a package requiring the 4.0 branch.

Comment: hi I took a screenshot, how does this look to you: https://maxniko.tinytake.com/sf/MjM1MTU2Nl83MTc1MzM2 as far as I can see there is no package in my app that requires anything over 3.0, for example first command you mentioned composer why symfony/event-dispatcher gives this:
symfony/http-kernel  v3.3.6  requires  symfony/event-dispatcher (~2.8|~3.0)

and grep command shows me 4 files and nonone are asking for above 3.0 Any idea where 4.0 is being required? I find this really puzzling...

Comment: btw I am using laravel and laravel requires some of symfony packages to work, but I have not run "composer update" so that by some chance some of core laravel files got new requirements, etc, I specifically run "composer update igaster/laravel-theme" and this command gets my version of it from repo, where I did some basic updates inside php file... If you got any more ideas please share, I am puzzled

Comment: I just run composer update and noticed this: Updating symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.3.6 => v3.4.4) Downloading: 100% so I am laravel is not asking for 4.0.0 for sure, and running grep returns no other composer.json that asks for that package...

Comment: thanks for your help, after running composer update so that whole project is updated, I was able to get the latest code from my own fork as well, not sure what happened before though... if you have any idea about that, let me know, if not I've rated you and accepted the answer since it had enough info in it to teach me new stuff...